# python : lxml xpath tag name with colon

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

i have to parse some feed, but one of the element (tag) is with `colon` `<dc:creator>leemore23</dc:creator>`

how can i parse it using `lxml`?  so i have done it in this way

```
r = requests.get('http://www.site.com/feed/')
foo = (r.content).replace("dc:creator","dc")
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(foo)
for article_node in tree.xpath('//item'):
    data['dc'] = article_node.xpath('.//dc')[0].text.strip()
```

but i think there is a better way, something like

```
data['dc'] = article_node.xpath('.//dc:creator')[0].text.strip()
```

or

```
data['dc'] = article_node.xpath('.//dc|creator')[0].text.strip()
```

so without replacing

what can you advice me ?

Comment: I suspect you need to take a look at the [`feedparser` library](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dc:` prefix indicates a [XML namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/NOTE-xml-names-0119). Use the [elementtree API namespace support](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) to deal with it, not just remove it from your input. As it happens, `dc` usually refers to [Dublin Core metadata](http://dublincore.org/documents/dc-xml-guidelines/).

You need to determine the full namespace URL, then use that URL in your XPath queries:

```
DCNS = 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'
creator = article_node.xpath('.//{{{0}}}creator'.format(DCNS))
```

Here I used the recommended `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/` namespace URL for the dublin core prefix.

You can normally determine the URL from the `.nsmap` property; your root element *probably* has the following `.nsmap` attribute:

```
{'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'}
```

and thus you can change your code to:

```
creator = article_node.xpath('.//{{{0}}}creator'.format(article_node.nsmap['dc']))
```

This can be simplified further still by passing the `nsmap` dictionary to the `xpath()` method as the `namespaces` keyword, at which point you can use the prefix in your xpath expression:

```
creator = article_node.xpath('.//dc:creator', namespaces=article_node.nsmap)
```

Comment: it works with namespaces, but there is a problem.  tag (dc:creator) has cdata text , it is not parsed.. if there is simple text, everything is ok, but with cdata it doesnt work. any idea?

Comment: @yital9: How are you accessing the text contents of the tag? LXML normally *removes* the CDATA 'wrapper' when using the normal APIs.

Comment: if there is simple text (without cdata) article_node.xpath('.//dc:creator', namespaces = dc)[0].text.strip() returns text, but if there is cdata article_node.xpath('.//dc:creator', namespaces = dc) returns [] and article_node.xpath('.//dc:creator', namespaces = dc)[0].text.strip() raises exception.

Comment: @yital9: Can you give us some example input?

Comment: of course, http://www.goptionsblog.com/feed/ here :  <dc:creator> is parsed with namespaces OK, but <content:encoded> is not..

Comment: @yital9: That's a *different* namespace. You need to use the correct prefix; `article_node.xpath('.//content:encoded', namespaces=article_node.nsmap)` *does* return a value. When you get an exception, check wether or not your code actually *found* any elements.

Comment: @yital9: Why are you trying to parse atom feeds yourself when `feedparser` does a great job of this already, btw?

Answer (score 2):

The `dc:` indicates a namespace. When using `lxml`'s `xpath` method, use the [`namespaces` parameter](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes) to search for elements in a namespace.

So, in your case, using the dublin core prefix supplied by @MartijnPieters,

```
r = requests.get('http://www.site.com/feed/')
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)
ns = {'dc':'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'}
for article_node in tree.xpath('//item'):
    data['dc'] = article_node.xpath('.//dc:creator', namespaces = ns)[0].text.strip()
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot! but a have a problem,  tag (dc:creator) has cdata text , it is not parsed.. if there is simple text, everything is ok, but with cdata it doesnt work..